# limit the use of server resources from php

Tags: php, resources

On my web app I have to generate some pdf and chart files. The thing is that when the user need to generate those files, the server arrives to 100%.

ATM I'm thinking to use a cron which will generate the reports that the user might need and to use just a part of the servers resources for longer periods of time, rather than all the resources on a certain moment.

This is what I'm thinking from the theoretical point of view. I might be wrong. Please correct me. Do you know how can I accomplish that with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways you might do this (and yes, you can do it from PHP).

However the big question is what you really want to achieve.

At the end of the day, it doesn't matter if your server CPU is maxed out by a single process, *as long as that process has minimal effect on everything else the server is doing*. So the first thing you need to do is look at what's happenning to all the other requests on the system.

If you do see a significant adverse effect then the solutions are to:

1. run the required processing in a sandbox with limits on the amount of resource it can use
2. run the process on a different machine where it the effect on other processes will be reduced to an acceptable level
3. run the process at a time when there are fewer other processes to be scheduled

Running the process via cron would be an example of option 3, but you explicitly asked how to implement option 1.

Since the bottleneck appears to be CPU, and again *if you see an effect on other transactions* then two solutions for method 1 on a Linux box would be:

1. run the processing in a seperate process started via 'nice'
2. If you're running in a non-threaded environment, renice the curent pid (but remember to reset the priority when it completes).

You don't need a second machine for the 2nd method - you could use taskset to set the processor for the majority of process to (e.g.) all but one of your cores - and reserve a core for running the heavy processes.

Regardless, you should familiarize yourself with the problems of invoking long-running processes via a webserver.

Note, using cron would be a sensible approach if you want to generate the files before they are requested - but if you want to do it on demand, then 'at' would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with PHP.

There are a few ways to limit CPU usage of a process with Linux. I found this one to be the most elegant: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/